# Understanding AuthServerWhitelist and AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist chrome policy registers?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, authentication, single-sign-on

What's the differences between these two chrome policy registers `AuthServerWhitelist` and `AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist`?

I started doubting when I've found out those two registers while I was trying to automate a login for an intra-net.

First I tried out with `AuthServerWhitelist` and it didn't work.

Then I set up both `AuthServerWhitelist` and `AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist` and it worked.

I cannot see right now what's the difference, although I read they have two different functions.

[Chromium Policies list link](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3)

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the two is related to Kerberos, impersonation levels and the difference between impersonation and delegation.

In simple terms (I'm not an expert):

`AuthServerWhitelist` specifies which servers are allowed for integrated authentication. By default, however, this only supports *impersonation* not delegation. 
So, if you add a server to `AuthServerWhitelist`, you can, for example, log in to a website which can then impersonate your user. However, let's say that website would further want to connect and authenticate to an SQL Server database *on behalf of your user*. That would not work since this is *delegation*.

Adding the server additionally to `AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist` should enable that delegation use-case, provided you are using Kerberos (Negotiate) and everything has been set up correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe important for all of you searching, the Key `AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist` got renamed to `AuthNegotiateDelegateAllowlist` in case you are running into trouble now.